# How to upgrade sails js project to version 0.10

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I've been checking out sails js and wanted to try the associations on the new version 0.10. How do I upgrade my project to version 0.10?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way is to create a new Sails project and copy your old controllers, policies, views, services, and assets over. As far as I know, there's no direct "upgrade" method from 0.9.x to 0.10.x.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Kao give a good answer for the start.

There is a part in the docs you should look after copying all: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Upgrading

Answer (score 0):

I recently posted to the Sails Google Group about this. My post is a basic procedure that follows Kevin's suggestion.

It might help to have a quick look:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sailsjs/FGqe_t61kJ8